# How to access yeast-cyc in a programmatic way to extract the GO terms?

Tags: python, genomics, public-dataset

I am a newbie in Bioinformatics, I want to extract the GO terms from yeast-cyc,
which is items in the Go terms tab of this page https://yeast.biocyc.org/gene?orgid=YEAST&id=G3O-29622#tab=GO , not one page but one database like *Saccharomyces cerevisiae S288c*.

Is there an API or python lib can help us finish this task? I had found biocyc in pypi, but I did not found Go terms was involved in this API.

If the API is not convinient, can I download some dataset in which my required items is include?

Comment: Not sure if I've misunderstood, but if you want the GO terms for yeast you can get them from https://www.uniprot.org/uniprotkb?query=(taxonomy_id:559292). Using the UniProt system you can then generate an API endpoint URL for your query, e.g. here are the GO terms for all yeast genes: https://rest.uniprot.org/uniprotkb/stream?fields=accession%2Cid%2Cprotein_name%2Cgene_names%2Cgo&format=tsv&query=%28%28taxonomy_id%3A559292%29%29 (use `wget` or `cURL` to pull the data); does that help?

Comment: Thanks, it is the data I need.

Comment: Great! I'll turn my comment into an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the GO terms for yeast from UniProt, e.g. https://uniprot.org/uniprotkb?query=(taxonomy_id:559292).

Using the UniProt website you can generate an API endpoint URL for your query, e.g. here are the GO terms for all yeast genes: https://rest.uniprot.org/uniprotkb/stream?fields=accession%2Cid%2Cprotein_name%2Cgene_names%2Cgo&format=tsv&query=%28%28taxonomy_id%3A559292%29%29

You can download this data using `wget` or `cURL`, e.g.

```
wget -O yeast_go_terms.tsv "https://rest.uniprot.org/uniprotkb/stream?fields=accession%2Cid%2Cprotein_name%2Cgene_names%2Cgo&format=tsv&query=%28%28taxonomy_id%3A559292%29%29"
```